# Better way to use LINQ To XML for an HTML Page

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am looking for specific items on a web page.
What I did (to test, so far) is working just fine, but is really ugly to my eyes. I would like to get suggestions to do this in a more concise manner, that is ONE Linq query instead of 2 now....

```
        document.GetXDocument();
        string xmlns = "{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}";
        var AllElements = from AnyElement in document.fullPage.Descendants(xmlns + "div")
                          where AnyElement.Attribute("id") != null && AnyElement.Attribute("id").Value == "maincolumn"
                          select AnyElement;
        // this first query bring only one LARGE Element.

        XDocument subdocument = new XDocument(AllElements);

        var myElements = from item in subdocument.Descendants(xmlns + "img")
                         where String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Attribute("src").Value.Trim()) != true
                         select item;

        foreach (var element in myElements)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine(element.Attribute("src").Value.Trim());                                                          
        }
        Assert.IsNotNull(myElements.Count());
```

I know I could directly look for "img", but I want to be able to get other types of items in those pages, like links and some text.

I strongly doubt this is the best way!

Comment: Consider to use Html Agility Pack: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: That'll work with conforming xhtml, but as soon as you get non-wellformed html, your solution will break. You might want to use something like [Tidy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy) as a precursor to loading up an XDocument, if you insist on parsing webpages as xml.

Answer (score 1):

The same logic in single query:

```
var myElements = from element in document.fullPage.Descendants(xmlns + "div")
                          where element.Attribute("id") != null 
                          && element.Attribute("id").Value == "maincolumn"
                          from item in new XDocument(element).Descendants(xmlns + "img")
                          where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Attribute("src").Value.Trim()) 
                          select item;
```

Comment: I actually think your comment was a better (more rubust) answer ;-)

Comment: @2kay Is there any way to extract content from this webpage using your logic ? This is my question I asked before.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833388/how-can-i-use-linq-to-xml-to-extract-content-from-webpage-in-c-sharp-or-in-xamar?noredirect=1#comment78626441_45833388. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on parsing the web page as XML, try this:

```
var elements =
    from element in document.Descendants(xmlns + "div")
    where (string)element.Attribute("id") == "maincolumn"
    from element2 in element.Descendants(xmlns + "img")
    let src = ((string)element2.Attribute("src")).Trim()
    where String.IsNullOrEmpty(src)
        select new {
            element2,
            src
    };

foreach (var item in elements) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.src);
}
```

Notes:

- What is the type of `document`? I am assuming it's an `XDocument`. If that is the case, you can use `Descendants` directly on `XDocument`. (OTOTH if `document` is an `XDocument`, where does that `fullPath` property come from?)
- Cast the `XAttribute` to a string. If it's empty, the result of the cast will be null. This will save on the double check. (This doesn't offer any performance benefits.)
- Use `let` to "save" a value for later reuse, in this case for use in the foreach. Unless all you need is that final Assert, in which case it might be more efficient to use `Any` instead of `Count`. `Any` only has to iterate over the first result in order to return a value; `Count` has to iterate over all of them.
- Why is `subdocument` of type `XDocument`? Wouldn't `XElement` be the appropriate type?
- You can also use `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` to check for whitespace in `src`, instead of `String.IsNullOrEmpty`, assuming you want to process the `src` as is, with any whitespace it might have.