# How can I use Linq to XML to extract content from webpage in C# or in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, linq, xamarin.android

I have attached an image and[image] would like to get content from expanded `<div> .... </div>` using Linq to XML in C#. I tried this way but could not sort it out.

```
  XDocument.Parse(content); // this is Linq to XML
            XElement root = XElement.Load(url);
            IEnumerable<XElement> tests =
                from el in root.Elements("Div")
                where (string)el.Element("Confused") == "Confused"
                select e
            foreach (XElement el in tests)
                Console.WriteLine((string)el.Attribute("Confused"));
```

If there is any simple way to extract content from webpage having this kind of structure using any other techniques including ***XmlDocument, XmlPullParser or LinqToXml***, I will appreciate.
Thank you.

Edited as requested:

```
    <div class="story-body__inner" property="articleBody">
        <figure class="media-landscape has-caption full-width lead">
            <span class="image-and-copyright-container">

                <img class="js-image-replace" alt="US President Donald Trump arrives to speak at a &quot;Make America Great Again&quot; rally in Phoenix, Arizona, on August 22, 2017" src="https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/5256/production/_97487012_ad54fff5-3ff7-41ec-9e30-c239de238cc4.jpg" width="976" height="549" data-highest-encountered-width="660">



                 <span class="off-screen">Image copyright</span>
                 <span class="story-image-copyright">AFP</span>

            </span>

            <figcaption class="media-caption">
                <span class="off-screen">Image caption</span>
                <span class="media-caption__text">
                    Donald Trump touched on immigration, healthcare and his enemies during the Arizona rally
                </span>
            </figcaption>

        </figure><p class="story-body__introduction">Donald Trump has vowed to close down the government if necessary to build his wall along the Mexico border.</p><p>The US president told supporters at a "Make America Great Again" rally in Phoenix, Arizona, that the opposition Democrats were being "obstructionist".</p><p>During the 80-minute speech, he also took aim at the media, blaming them for giving far right groups "a platform".</p><p>But he selectively quoted his initial response to violence at a far-right rally that left one woman dead.</p><p>He omitted the controversial claim that <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-40943425" class="story-body__link">"many sides" had to shoulder the blame</a> for violence in Charlottesville, Virginia.</p><div id="bbccom_mpu_1_2_3" class="bbccom_slot mpu-ad" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="bbccom_advert">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /**/
            (function() {
                if (window.bbcdotcom && bbcdotcom.adverts && bbcdotcom.adverts.slotAsync) {
                    bbcdotcom.adverts.slotAsync('mpu', [1,2,3]);
                }
            })();
            /**/
        </script>
    </div>
</div><p>In his wide-ranging speech, Mr Trump also said he thought he would "probably end up terminating Nafta", the trade deal with Mexico and Canada.</p><p>On North Korea, the president sounded a hopeful note about the possibility of a reduction in tensions over Pyongyang's missile tests and nuclear programme.</p><p>Referring to North Korean leader Kim Jong-un, Mr Trump said: "I respect the fact that he is starting to respect us".</p><p>"And maybe - probably not, but maybe - something positive can come about," he added.</p><ul class="story-body__unordered-list">
<li class="story-body__list-item"><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-40948812" class="story-body__link">Charlottesville: What made Trump remarks so offensive?</a></li>
<li class="story-body__list-item"><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-40946386" class="story-body__link">Bush presidents wade into Trump furore </a></li>
<li class="story-body__list-item"><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-40943041" class="story-body__link">Nafta: What is at stake?</a></li>
</ul><p>But while his comments were met with cheers inside the conference centre, anti-Trump protesters who had gathered outside the rally clashed with police after the rally had finished.</p><p>Police deployed tear gas after the protesters threw bottles and rocks, Reuters news agency reported.</p><figure class="media-landscape has-caption full-width">
            <span class="image-and-copyright-container">


                <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/cpsprodpb/A076/production/_97487014_7815d739-c520-4475-a24d-8f5ccfcca705.jpg" datasrc="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/320/cpsprodpb/A076/production/_97487014_7815d739-c520-4475-a24d-8f5ccfcca705.jpg" class="responsive-image__img js-image-replace" alt="Large inflated figures of Sheriff Joe Arpaio and President Trump are seen above ant-Trump protesters outside the Phoenix Convention Center" width="976" height="549" data-highest-encountered-width="624">


                 <span class="off-screen">Image copyright</span>
                 <span class="story-image-copyright">Getty Images</span>

            </span>

            <figcaption class="media-caption">
                <span class="off-screen">Image caption</span>
                <span class="media-caption__text">
                    Protesters hold up an inflatable Joe Arpaio, whom Mr Trump hinted he would pardon
                </span>
            </figcaption>

        </figure><p>President Trump began and finished his speech by urging the American people to come together.</p><p>But he quickly turned on familiar foes, beginning with the media, which he said had misrepresented his "perfect" words in the wake of the violence in Charlottesville, where Heather Heyer was killed after a car ploughed into a crowd of people protesting against far-right demonstrators including neo-Nazis.</p><p>He accused "truly dishonest people in the media and the fake media" of "trying to take away our history and heritage" because, he said, they "don't like our country".</p><p>He quoted his own initial public response to what happened in Charlottesville.</p><p>"This is what I said on Saturday: 'We're closely following the terrible events unfolding in Charlottesville, Virginia,' - this is me speaking. 'We condemn in the strongest possible terms this egregious display of hatred, bigotry and violence.' That's me speaking on Saturday, right after the event," he said.</p><p>But what he actually said on 12 August was: "We condemn in the strongest possible terms this egregious display of hatred, bigotry and violence on many sides, on many sides."</p><p>Mr Trump's attention then turned to immigration, and to the Democrats who he said were "putting all of America's safety at risk" by opposing the wall he wants to build along the US's southern border with Mexico.</p><ul class="story-body__unordered-list"><li class="story-body__list-item"><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/resources/idt-d60acebe-2076-4bab-90b4-0e9a5f62ab12" class="story-body__link">Six things that could topple Trump's wall</a></li></ul><p>He said immigration officers who worked in the area said it was "vital" to stem the flow of illegal immigrants.</p><p>Mr Trump concluded: "If we have to close down government, we are building that wall."</p><p>Mr Trump also used the rally to hint he would pardon controversial former Arizona sheriff Joe Arpaio, a man who rose to national prominence because of his tough stance against illegal immigration.</p><figure class="media-landscape has-caption full-width">
            <span class="image-and-copyright-container">


                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKhI+py+0Po5yUFQA7" datasrc="https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/320/cpsprodpb/EE96/production/_97487016_3eff3038-16fe-4f5a-963a-b36339e3320e.jpg" class="responsive-image__img responsive-image__img--loading js-image-replace" alt="Supporters of U.S. President Donald Trump cheer him at a campaign rally in Phoenix, Arizona, U.S., August 22, 2017." width="976" height="549">


                 <span class="off-screen">Image copyright</span>
                 <span class="story-image-copyright">Reuters</span>

            </span>

            <figcaption class="media-caption">
                <span class="off-screen">Image caption</span>
                <span class="media-caption__text">
                    Supporters could be heard to chant "CNN sucks" during the rally
                </span>
            </figcaption>

        </figure><p>He told the crowd Mr Arpaio - who was <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-40780659" class="story-body__link">found guilty of criminal contempt</a> in July - "is going to be just fine", but would not formally pardon him at the moment because "I don't want to cause any controversy".</p><p>His comments directly contradicted those of White House spokeswoman Sarah Sanders, who said on Tuesday "there will be no discussion of that today".</p><p>Mr Arpaio, 85, was found to have violated a judge's 2001 order that he cease detaining migrants who are not suspected of having committed a state crime.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its easier to help if you attach an example of the xml as code and not image. Where in your example does div have a child element of "confused"?

Comment: There is no child element called 'confused', I am confused to put on....

Comment: For the given html what do you want to get?

Comment: Can you please have a look this link I want the news content from news headline to end of news content from this link http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-41020779

Comment: I am not sure from the description whether you use some specific web page or you want to use variety of web pages. Generally speaking, quality of html is poor and nearly all pages don't validate as proper which makes them impossible to be used with XmlDocument. You should try HTML Agility Pack to nuget to parse the page. If that's acceptable I'll write that as the answer.

Comment: @IvanIčin Thank you for your response. Actually it was my asked question here can you please have a look this first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830133/how-to-parse-html-content-from-json-linked-url

Comment: @IvanIčin Thank you for your response. Yes I decided to use HTML Agility Pack as my html document is from json linked url which has almost similar structure. What I need here is how to query that exact div and whole inner html so that I can load using webview later on. Thank you.